# Cookies.get() is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, cookie-httponly

EDIT: its work / i can get the cookies value when the httpOnly = false, Why?

Im using js-cookie package,

When I open the chrome dev tools, there is a cookie **token**.

but when im using **Cookies.get('token')**, result is **undefined**.

and using **Cookies.get()** also the result is **undefined**.

this is my code:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
const [token, setToken] = useState(Cookies.get())
// const [token, setToken] = useState(Cookies.get('token'))

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(token) //undefined

    CheckAuth(token)
                .then(data => {
                    setLoggedInUser(data.user)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    Cookies.remove('token')
                    setErrorMessage(error.message)
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    setLoading(false)
                })
}, [])
```

[image]

Comment: Put `Cookies.get()` in a useEffect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's the same, the result is undefined

Comment: edit: i can get the result when the HttpOnly is false

Comment: is that how HttpOnly works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s a valid behaviour.
Using httpOnly = true, flag while generating a cookie, makes the cookie a protected one.
And if a certain browser supports httpOnly flag,
It won’t allow the client side script to use such a protected cookie.
Kindly find more details here,
https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly